# Is there anything I can do if I get a downvote after my answer has been accepted by the OP?

Tags: discussion

Now, this has happened twice. I have got downvote for my answer once after the OP commented that my answer was relevant and the other time when my answer was accepted by the OP. The link to the second instance is [Missing root tag in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015716/missing-root-tag-in-xml/25015894#25015894). There was no comment provided in the second instance.
Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Improve the answer! Add thorough explanation, references, lay it out nicely, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answers are not just helpful for **one** person, but for all the other people with similar problems who might come along in the future.

It is possible for the OP to think the answer was helpful, but for other people to think the answer is incomplete, is a poor way of fixing that particular problem, doesn't have enough code, lacks sufficient explanation of the code, etc.  So it's not uncommon to get an accept and downvotes, or for a late but very useful answer to get lots of upvotes while the OP has long since accepted the first answer posted and never come back.

That said, if it's just one downvote without commentary, and you can't see any obvious issue with the answer, I wouldn't worry too much.  It may be simply that someone thought the question should have been closed not answered (I see the question has a downvote and some close votes on it).

Answer (score 6):

You can not force someone to remove their downvote or comment. That's their decision. What you can do is read over the question again and make sure that it is completely correct and high quality.  Users are welcome to use their downvotes as they please (except for serial downvoting, of course).

Comment: The problem is not the downvoting though its the fact that people downvote and leave no reason as to why. How can you improve something that someone else has an opinion on when that person fails to make their opinion known?

Comment: @KyleT The most frequent reason for such downvoting is probably that the post is so low quality that the downvoter may find the explanation to be obvious. Another reason is that the question is so bad that an answer should not have been given. Sometimes it is just out of spite, but that is usually well handled. This question was asking *what to do*. The answer is simply to make sure that the post is high quality. As to how you can do that without knowing the exact reason, do some more research on the subject and assure that your understanding is fully correct.